Crops not spawning for Bantu in Ancient Era
While playing as the Bantu in the Ancient Era, I encountered an issue where crops stopped spawning approximately ten turns into the era.
Steps to Reproduce:

Start a game as the Bantu.

Progress to the Ancient Era.

Play for approximately ten turns.

Attempt to search for new crops in the world.


Attaching a GitHub repository with a crops_stopped_spawning.ctr save file
Observed result: The spawn of new crops disappears about ten turns into the Ancient Era, making it impossible to breed Bantu tribes.
Expected result: The crops should be able to continuously spawn in the Ancient Era.
Game Version: 1.0.26.4449

Are you using any mods?

I am only subscribed to huge earth map - all dlc natural wonders, but I am using random map for this game.
